# woocommerce: how can woocommerce_form_field take the value of the field to be created as 3rd argument?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'add_box_option_to_checkout' );
function add_box_option_to_checkout( $checkout ) {
    echo '<div id="message_fields">';
    woocommerce_form_field( 'add_gift_box', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('add_gift_box form-row-wide'),

        'label'         => esc_html__( 'Gift Box + 1€', '@@pkg.textdomain' ),
        'placeholder'   => '',
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'add_gift_box' ));
    echo '</div>';
}
```

I came across the above snippet on this page: https://gist.github.com/heldervilela/4d1fac4d7e9c1cbf7af56656a1f0db8b

According to woocommerce's document, function `woocommerce_form_field` is used to create field and its 3rd argument is the value of the form field to be created. So

```
    woocommerce_form_field( 'add_gift_box', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('add_gift_box form-row-wide'),

        'label'         => esc_html__( 'Gift Box + 1€', '@@pkg.textdomain' ),
        'placeholder'   => '',
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'add_gift_box' ));
```

will create a checkbox named 'add_gift_box'. What I don't understand is, while it has not been created, how can this function take `$checkout->get_value( 'add_gift_box' )` as 3rd argument, which I suppose is used to get the value of the field.

Answer (score 0):

The `woocommerce_form_field` function accepts 3 arguments which is the `key`, `argument` and `value` which has default value `null`

what happens is, it will first check if this code `$checkout->get_value( 'add_gift_box' )` returns any value, and if there is, the value will be assign on the form field, otherwise it wont have any value in it.

You can check the full function code here -> https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-template-functions.html#source-view.2726

You'll see it simply check and assign a default value if the 3rd argument value is null

```
function woocommerce_form_field( $key, $args, $value = null ) {
    .
    .
    .
    if ( is_null( $value ) ) {
        $value = $args['default'];
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: What I don't understand is, since the field hasn't been created yet when this function executes, isn't `$checkout->get_value( 'add_gift_box' )` always return NULL?

Comment: even if 99% of the time its null, there is still 1% chance where the field has already been created and already has a value like if the user already filled up those field, closes the browser tab, then open the same tab , goes to checkout page, that function handles that kind of situation by assigning a value to it if its already there